# How to launch terminal and pass it a command using Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, terminal

I want to programmatically open a terminal and paste a command into it like "cd /Users/...".

I can start a terminal using this code, but I don't know how to execute command

```
guard let url = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: "com.apple.Terminal") else { return }

let path = "/bin"
let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
configuration.arguments = \[path\]
NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: url, configuration: configuration, completionHandler: nil)
```

It is very important to use the sandbox, the Process command is not suitable.

Comment: From the docs for `NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration arguments`: *"If the calling process is sandboxed, the system ignores the value of this property."*.

Comment: It might be better if your question is about the actual task you are trying to achieve. Why are you trying to launch a terminal just to change the working folder in that terminal process?

Comment: This is a real task. There is such a function, for example, in the Sourcetree, if you click on the Terminal button

Comment: Sourcetree after opening terminal goes to repository folder. I also need this feature.

Comment: But is SourceTree sandboxed? No it isn’t so that is quite different from your requirements.

Comment: Is there any way to pass the command to the code that I wrote above?

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to achieve is to open a terminal on a specific location all you have to do is to use this code:

```
let pathToOpen = "/Users/admin/Desktop"
let url = URL(string:"terminal://"+pathToOpen)! 
NSWorkspace.shared.open(url)
```

If you are trying just to run a command in terminal and show the output in your app, here is another useful code snippet:

```
func shell(_ command: String) -> String {

let task = Process()
let pipe = Pipe()

task.standardOutput = pipe
task.standardError = pipe
task.arguments = ["-c", command]
task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
task.standardInput = nil
task.launch()

let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!

return output
}

//Usage:
shell("yourCommandHere")
//please note that you are not allowed to use commands that require sudo
```